# How do I simply set the ModelStateError from the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, modelstate

So what is happening is that I have a condition within my override of the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method in my custom authorize attribute. Up to this point, I've been throwing a 403 which gets picked up and redirects to a custom error page. Well now, that's not really what I want. What I actually want is to show the same login page but add a message to the validation summary "You do not have access to this resource.", that way it's a bit more user friendly. It'll indicate that your creds were good, but you don't belong here.

I thought something like this would work:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // passed authentication, failed authorization
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {           
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Not Authorized");
        return;
    }

    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

But this isn't working. What's happening is that the login page simply reloads. So this makes me feel like I'm close, but I need that model error to show up.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
It would seem that the Controller that I'm adding an error to here is actually controller of whichever action had the attribute that led to here. I need to somehow add the error to the login controller. Not sure if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the base method here:

```
base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
```

If you are using Forms Authentication this base method simply redirects you to the login page. And a redirect means a new HTTP request from the client. The current context and whatever you stored in it is lost. Well, to be more precise, the base method is returning a 401 HTTP status code which is then intercepted by the FormsAuthenticationModule which redirects to the login page defined in your web.config. But this implementation details is not important.

What you could do is perform the redirect yourself to the login page instead of leaving it to the base method. You could do this by setting the `filterContext.Result` property to a `RedirectToRouteResult` instance. In this case you could pass the error message as a query string parameter.

---

UPDATE:

According to your updated question it seems that you are calling `return;` after setting the ModelState value and not calling the base method and thus no redirect will happen to the login url. You could in this case return some error view by setting the `filterContext.Result` to an instance of a `ViewResult` in which view you could use the value you stored in the ModelState.

Comment: Sorry, I actually put a return after setting the model error. The problem with passing the error as a query string (i've tried this) is that if you attempt to enter your creds again, it'll reload that url without the query string, so there is no message at all

Comment: Yeah, but if you just return which view will be rendered? You never set the `filterContext.Result` property. If you want to render some generic error view you could do so by setting it to an instance of a `ViuewResult`. In this case you could use the ModelState value in this view.

Comment: True, but i don't want a generic error view. I just want to have an error displayed back at the login page.

Comment: But the login page won't be displayed. You disabled it by not calling the base method. If you want to redirect you could either use a query string parameter or probably TempData as well but personally I would go with a query string parameter.

Comment: While chatting with you, I actually did both. I throw an HttpError instead, redirect that error to an error Action which stores the error into temp data. Then the login page reads it out and adds it to the modelstate there